# Consider the ring $R = \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$. Find all the units in $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Am I correct in thinking that an element in $R$ takes the form $(a/b, c/d)$, and that each element has a corresponding inverse $(b/a, d/c)$ for all $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$ also in $R$? That would mean every element is a unit, and that this is a division ring, right?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Q}x\mathbb{Q}$? Do you mean $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @JoshChen The set of all rational numbers crossed with the set of all rational numbers.

Comment: The real numbers is $\Bbb R$, whereas $\Bbb Q$ denotes the rational numbers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, its been a long night. I meant to say rationals. I've corrected it.

Comment: @LMNOP A $\LaTeX$ point: use `\times` rather than `x` for crossed products, multiplication, etc. This is because `\times` yields $\times$ while `x` yields $x$.

Comment: Consider $(1,0) \cdot (0, 1)$.

Comment: I have changed $\mathbb{R}$ to $R$, as the first symbol usually refers to the real numbers. And I have used the standard bracket notation for pairs.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thanks.

Comment: @user1729 Ok, will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because multiplication is applied component-wise, you can simply look at what the units are in $\mathbb{Q}$. An element in $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is a unit, if and only if both its components are units.

And it is $\mathbb{Q}^\times = \mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ ($\mathbb{Q}^\times$ is the unit group of $\mathbb{Q}$).

So $(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q})^\times$ would be $(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\})\times(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\})$.

Comment: Oh, right, $0$ can't be an inverse, so when you say $\mathbb{Q} \setminus {0}$, the "$\setminus$" just means the $\mathbb{Q}$ except for 0, correct?

Comment: yes that's right. And it's \setminus in $\LaTeX$

Comment: Haha, right, thanks.

Comment: In general, for commutative rings $R$ and $S$, we have $(R \times S)^\times = R^\times \times S ^\times$. That’s one proof of $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)$ for coprime $m$ and $n$ and $\phi$ Euler’s function.